# magento 1.9 back-end settings area with error

Tags: magento-1.9

good morning friends, i need urgent help, i'm desperate.
I was trying to correct a problem in the product evaluation form and tried to disable some non-native extensions on the backend to check for any conflicts.
After that, the settings page was completely blank.

follow the inage below

I'm not even able to invert the process because the modules I disabled, it doesn't appear for me to be able to enable them again.

[image]

In addition, it also affected the front end, without CSS and JS from the frontend.
I already cleared the cache, I tried to see the log, I tried to enable the modules via the app \ etc \ modules \ path, but nothing,

Could you tell me how I could solve this?

the version is 1.9

Comment: Please enabled error report from index.php and check in which file it is generating error.
It will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your log file. Enable error display in index.php file and enable all extensions those you have disabled. You can do this in app/etc/modules/extension.xml file where you find active tag make it true. Your extension will be enable. After that try to disable extensions one by one and check for which it creates a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning Mayur Sisodiya, I came to behave according to your guidance and nothing
no type of error appears in the log about it.